# ($\epsilon$,$\delta$) Definition of limit

Tags: calculus, limits

**Definition** $lim_{x\longrightarrow c}$$f(x)= l$ $\Longrightarrow$for any $\epsilon$>0
, we can find a $\delta$ $>$ $0$ such that if $0 <|x-c|<$ $\delta$
 Then $|f(x)-l|$ $<$$\epsilon$

**My Questions** Please clarify my doubts by answering these question.

$\left(1\right)$There is a statement used in books very often that
the value $\delta$ is corresponding to $\epsilon$. What does ``
corresponding mean here'' .does it means any of the following ?

(a) $\epsilon$> $\delta$

(b) $\epsilon$< $\delta$

(c) $\epsilon$= $\delta$

Can i say any one of them$\left\{ (a),(b)and(c)\right\} $ is always
true whenever limit exist.

Comment: no, the value of $\delta$ corresponding to $\varepsilon$ means that you can pick different deltas for different epsilons (for example you can take $\delta = 2\varepsilon$), equivalently, you can think about $\delta$ as a function depending on $\varepsilon$.

Comment: there is no particular relationship between $\delta$ and $\epsilon$. You do these sort of proofs by assuming you have an $\epsilon>0$ and showing that there is a $\delta$ which bounds $|x-c|$ if $\epsilon$ bounds $|f(x)-1|$.

Comment: If the function is nice enough (for instance, if $f(x) = \pm x + d$ for some number $d$), then choosing $\delta = \epsilon$ is enough. Often, though, in exercices you will come across choices like $\delta = \min\{1, \frac{3\epsilon}{17}\}$.

Comment: @Arthur I think the function $f(x)=2x$ is pretty nice, but $\delta=\epsilon$ is not a good idea.

Comment: @5xum Does $2x$ look like it's on the form $\pm x + d$? Clearly, it's not nice _enough_, regardless of how you feel about it (for the record, I also think it's a nice function, most of the time).

Comment: @Arthur OK but then I suggest you reformulate your phrase "for instance". Saying "If $P$ (for instance, $p$ or $q$),..." this implies $p$ and $q$ are examples of $P$, but there may be others. The "for instance" reads like "e.g.", but you used it to mean "i e" which is better expressed by saying "specifically".

Comment: @5xum It sounds like you think those are all the functions that work, but they're not. Those functions _are_ just some examples. For a generalisation, we have $cx + d$ for $-1\leq c \leq 1$. You have a lot of others as well, like $\sin(cx + d)$ (with the same limitations on $c$ or $d$), or $\ln(x^n + m)$ for appropriate $n$ and $m$ (I don't want to calculate exact bounds right now, but $n = 2, m = 10$ works).

Comment: @Arthur OK, so here is my point. your phrase "nice enough" either means "of the form $\pm x \pm d$" (in which case, 'for instance' is a poor choice of words) or it doesn't. If it doesn't, then I think it's not a good phrase because it's too vague. (see again the example of $2x$, which some people may think is "nice", and probably even nicer than $\ln(x^2+10)$). In either case, I think your comment may serve to confuse the OP and any unversed future reader

Comment: @5xum I think Lipschitz with constant at most $1$ is a very objective niceness criterion (enough that such functions have an established name: short maps). I might not have given the most intuitive example to illustrate, but I stilll stand by what I said. I used "for instance" to make clear that functions on the form $\pm x + d$ are not the only functions that obey this, which is clearly true.

Comment: @Arthur I think it's a pretty nice "niceness" criterion too, but unless you specifically say that's your criterion, I think saying "nice" to describe a function can be misleading and I stand by that.

Comment: It's not my fault that you incorrectly assumed what you thought my niceness condition was from my single example.

Comment: I didn't misunderstand it. You didn't define it. There's a difference. And also, sure' it's not your fault, but then again, if **I** misunderstood it, there's a good chance someone else did as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it doesn't mean any of those three things.

It means that the choice of $\delta$ depends on the value of $\epsilon$.

For example, if $f(x)=x$, then you can choose $\delta=\epsilon$. If $f(x)=2x$, then you can choose $\delta=\frac\epsilon 2$.

---

Remember, the statement goes:

**For all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists some $\delta>0$ such that such and such**

Therefore, the statement is saying:

- Pick any $\epsilon > 0$
- Once you picked the $\epsilon$, I then choose my $\delta$
- I can guarantee that such and such will always be true.

So, in step $2$, I get to choose $\delta$ **after** you already chose your $\epsilon$, and in that sense, I call the $\delta$ I chose as the $\delta$ that corresponds to your choice of $\epsilon$.

Comment: Very beautifully explained +1.